# Put a breakpoint on one line and the program works. Move the breakpoint to the next line and it crashes

Tags: c#, debugging, runtime-error, race-condition

I have this code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.xml");

XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//myElement");  // Line 4

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // Line 6
{
    nodes[i].ParentNode.RemoveChild(nodes[i]);
}

doc.Save("output.xml");
```

If I put a breakpoint on line 4 the program works just fine. However, if I put a breakpoint on any line past that (such as 6), I get the `object reference not set to instance of object` error because nodes only has one item in it.

The program crashes every time I run it without breakpoints. If I put a breakpoint on line 4 though, nodes has the proper count of `85` and everything works perfectly.

Even If I do `Thread.Sleep(10000)` before and after line 4, the program still crashes because it only finds 1 node.

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Are you sure that there are at least 5 `myElement` nodes?  Why not check programmatically to ensure there aren't more/less?  Are you sure all of the notes have a parent node?

Comment: When you say "everything works perfectly", do you mean that you can hit run from that point and it works?

Comment: Can you post the contents of file.xml or at least partial?

Comment: @Servy: Yeah I'm sure because every time I put a breakpoint on line 4 there end up being 85. If I put a breakpoint on line 6 there is always only 1.

Comment: @Steve: I cannot but it the file is approximately 150 kilobytes. That might have something to do with it.

Comment: @RyanPeschel And when you actually open up the file in a text editor and look at it?  Also, as I said, why not check the size of the collection at runtime to verify it is large enough?

Comment: @Servy: Well I could check the size but that's irrelevant it's supposed to be 85 and it's showing up as 1. It's a bug at this point.

Comment: @RyanPeschel So I'm asking you to rule out the bug that the file itself doesn't have what you expect, rather than assuming this fairly straightforward C# code is severely bugged.

Comment: @RyanPeschel - Even if you just put in a `Console.WriteLine(nodes.Count());`....  If you get different results output when there's a breakpoint and when there isn't, there's clearly a problem.

Comment: @Servy: I switched this code to use XDocument instead and do the same thing and now it works flawlessly. Not sure what the problem was but it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the code to this and now it works flawlessly, breakpoints or not, 100% of the time:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");

List<XElement> nodes = doc.Descendants("myElement").ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    nodes[i].Remove();
}

doc.Save("output.xml");
```

Not sure why `SelectNodes` was giving me trouble but this solution seems to fix everything.

Comment: rather than that `for` loop I'd suggest `foreach(var node in nodes.Take(5)){...}`.